# how to fix and detect memory aliasing on pointers for better optimization in C

Tags: c, performance, pointers, optimization, compiler-optimization

What i understand from memory aliasing is that its the case where two pointers may reference the same memory location.

So when the compiler thinks there is aliasing it may take more cycles to complete the task since its trying to perform only safe optimizations. One way I think of fixing this is by changing the type of the pointer since the compiler wont assume that the pointers are aliased.

What are ways of knowing when there is memory aliasing and what are the best tricks to fix them?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of sticking to safe coding practices (like avoiding buffer over-runs and always setting pointers to NULL after they've been freed)? In C99, you can add a [restrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)  flag to the definitions of functions where two ore more pointers are expected to reference disjoint regions of memory.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage What do buffer overruns and NULL have to do with overlapping pointers? Restrict pointers are not just expected to always refer to different objects, they are absolutely required to do so.

Comment: @jforberg If the programmer *doesn't know* whether or not two pointers are capable of referencing the same location, then there's a problem with the program. Safe coding can help prevent this sort of situation. The `restrict` keyword is a declaration of intent. Call it what you will.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that two pointers will never overlap, you can use the **restrict** keyword from C99.

This may allow the compiler to do more aggressive optimisation in some cases. It also documents the semantics of your function better, showing that it will only work with non-overlapping pointers.

If you are **not** sure if the pointers overlap, you should not use the restrict keyword. The compiler will account for the possible case of overlapping pointers and will do the right thing.

**There is no middle ground here. You are either sure that your pointers do not overlap or you are not.**

If you are writing code where the (possible) efficiency boost matters, you can probably take the extra time to read the calling code and figure out if the pointers could overlap or not. There is no automatic tool which can do this for you, that I know of. Neither can I see how such a tool could work at all in the general case.

Comment: `restrict` is rather a contract between the function and the caller, stating that if the caller pass pointers that overlap, the code will break.